# reading status and giving user role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a command that gives a user a role if they have `.gg/` in their custom status. There are no error logs but the bot is not giving the role to the users who have this as their status.

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get('726517660279373986');
    const member = newPresence.member;
    const activities = member.user.presence.activities[0];

    if (activities && (activities.state.includes('.gg/') || activities.state.includes('discord.gg/'))) {
        return newPresence.member.roles.add(role);
    }
    else if (member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
        newPresence.member.roles.remove(role);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have the presence intent? What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: its still on discord 12 what is presence intent

Answer (score 1):

> Gateway Intents were introduced by Discord so bot developers can choose which events their bot receives based on which data it needs to function. Intents are named groups of pre-defined WebSocket events, which the discord.js client will receive.

You need the [privileged `GUILD_PRESENCE`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) Intent to be enabled for setting up a functional `presenceUpdate` listener.

You may enable it by going to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers) > Your Application > Bot > ( Scroll down and locate privileged intents ) > Turning on Presence intent.

This is what you'd be looking for:

[image: here's what you're looking for]